# Universal link which opens the calendar app

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

What is the universal link (deeplink) which opens the calendar app?

Is there any list of universal links or deeplinks for several Apple apps and also third party ones?

If the list will be maintained it is even better.

Answer (score 1):

The universal link which opens the calendar app is

```
CALSHOW://
```

There are also some websites with many universal links:

- [Universal links list](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-paths-for-shortcuts-0184033/)
- [Settings app URLs iOS 13](https://www.macstories.net/ios/a-comprehensive-guide-to-all-120-settings-urls-supported-by-ios-and-ipados-13-1/)